# How to arrange many thermal sensors in series?

Tags: temperature, thermal, thermocouple

Is there a kind of thermal sensor that only changes resistance if it is above 50'C and that can be wired in series?

I want to wire 50 thermal sensors on 50 batteries so that i can see if any one of them gets too hot.

Comment: Probably NTC thermistor?

Comment: A bimetal switch

Comment: Do you want to know which battery overheated and, if more than one, which ones, or do you just want an indication that at least one battery overheated? If it's the latter, Google "Klixon".

Comment: A PTC fuse:  RL3006-50-50-25-PTO, wired parallel like solid state bimetal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A re-settable thermal fuse, such as [this](http://au.rs-online.com/web/p/resettable-thermal-fuses/1769097/), could probably do what you're looking for.

Wire them all in series and place one on each battery. If any battery gets above 50C the fuse will trip and the circuit will break past the fuse. These are usually available in many different temperatures to suit your needs.